# Why does this query cause 'too many clauses'?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query with only a few 'shoulds' and 'filters', but one of the filters has a terms query with ~20,000 terms in it.  Our max_terms_count is 200k but this is complaining about 'clauses'.

> Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception [type=too_many_clauses, reason=too_many_clauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024]

I've written queries containing terms queries with far more terms than this.  Why is this query causing a 'too many clauses' error?  How can I rewrite this query to get the same result without the error?

```
{
    "query" : {
      "bool" : {
        "filter" : [
          {
            "nested" : {
              "query" : {
                "range" : {
                  "dateField" : {
                    "from" : "2019-12-03T21:34:30.653Z",
                    "to" : "2020-12-02T21:34:30.653Z",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : true,
                    "boost" : 1.0
                  }
                }
              },
              "path" : "observed_feeds",
              "ignore_unmapped" : false,
              "score_mode" : "none",
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          }
        ],
        "should" : [
          {
            "bool" : {
              "filter" : [
                {
                  "terms" : {
                    "ipAddressField" : [
                      "123.123.123.123",
                      "124.124.124.124",
                      ... like 20,000 of these
                    ],
                    "boost" : 1.0
                  }
                }
              ],
              "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
        "minimum_should_match" : "1",
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
}
```

Edit:  one note - The reason I'm wrapping the terms query in a should -> bool is because there are times where we need to have multiple terms queries OR'd together.  This happened to not be one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are facing this with terms query is because the `should` clause is outside `filter` clause and contributing to score calculation. This is the reason these terms are subject to max_clause_count. If score is not required for that part then you can rephrase you query as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "dateField": {
                  "from": "2019-12-03T21:34:30.653Z",
                  "to": "2020-12-02T21:34:30.653Z",
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            },
            "path": "observed_feeds",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "score_mode": "none",
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "ipAddressField": [
                          "123.123.123.123",
                          "124.124.124.124",
                          ... like 20,000 of these
                        ],
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This causes "[should] query malformed, no start_object after query name".  Wrapping 'should' in a bool fixes the error but still getting the max clauses error

Comment: My bad, missed to wrap `should` clause inside  `bool`. Fixed it.

Comment: Sorry I edited my earlier comment after you saw it I guess.  Still the same max clauses error

Comment: Oh boy.  OK - I simplified my example a TINY bit and that seems to be making the difference.  I'll follow up with a longer explanation

Comment: My `ipAddressField`, in reality, is a keyword field with an `ip`-typed sub field.  I'm trying to query the sub-field.  If I change my query to be against the main keyword field your solution works.  I'll change my question to reflect this.

Comment: Updated my question.  Need to be able to query `ipAddressField.ip` (the ip-typed sub field of the keyword field `ipAddressField`)

Comment: Oh, I had that in mind but missed out mentioning about it in my answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm still getting the error when structuring the query as you've suggested.  I only get the error when using a terms query against the ip subfield.  Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it answered my original question and create a new, simpler question for terms queries against ip fields.